# Midi to .wav conversion

Tags: midi, software, conversion, wav, tools

I'm looking for a program that turns my short MIDI-sequences into .wav files. 
That in itself isn't the problem, tho. The problem is that most programs append 1 or 2 seconds of silence at the end of each clip. I could just remove it by hand, I know but I got about 16 clips I would have to edit this way.
 That's why I'm hoping there is some kind of software (preferably freeware) that just won't add the seconds of silence at the end.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should look at why the extra duration is added. I'd suggest it is the tail from the final sample played - ensuring it has fully dcayed to zero. If you are sure the samples used are short and the tools you use are still adding seconds (none of the ones I use do) then it is easy to script silence removal in things like audigy or ffmpeg.

Comment: @RoryAlsop I checked and the Midis I'm using are just the four bars I wrote in GuitarPro. After I export them there's also only the four bars. But after conversion they're 2 seconds longer. But I'll now check out ffmpeg and see if it solves my problem.

Comment: I wasn't expecting more bars to appear - it's the samples that your midi is triggering. Is there reverb, or a long decay?

Answer (score 1):

A note has to ring out.  If you need to join multiple songs end-to-end without such delay, it is probably easiest to join them into one large Midi file first before converting to `.wav`.

Alternatively, if you can get or calculate the "nominal" length of the songs, you can combine the `.wav` files by addition, with each song shifted by the combined nominal length of the preceding ones.  That way your tail of 'silence' will get combined with the start of the next song.

Comment: It actually is one longer Song (or was) but I split it up into smaller parts so I could rearrange them randomly as background music for a game that's why I want to be able to play them end to end without delay.

Comment: If you want to make combinatorial game music you should consider using FMOD Studio (free for non-commercial use). It's (one of) the software sound designers use when dealing with games, and interfaces with things like Unity. It will let you create endlessly recombining music from smaller parts (and much more), and your problem would be trivial to address.

Answer (score 0):

A midi file is essentially a set of instructions to be executed by a computer program - unlike a .wav or .mp3 or .ogg, it is not a sound file and contains no waveforms. In order to create a sound file from a .mid file you have to play the .mid file and then record it in some way.